# Merging DataFrames without Duplicate Columns in R

Tags: r

I have three data sets that I would like to merge. My data is on companies in the SP500 and their corporate political activity. Of my datasets, one is named PAC, one is named Lobby and one is named BoardData. The datasets all have three columns in common: "ultorg", "sector", and "subind" as well as other columns unique to each dataset.

I would like to merge the three excel documents so that there is only one of each of those columns that has all of the other variables appended to it.

I have tried doing this on my own but I get a few problems. Specifically, I get several columns for ultorg/sector/subind (the variables the datasets have in common) and there are entries that are repeating in places where they shouldn't. For example, my board data only goes until 2015 but my lobbying data goes until 2000. Using the incorrect/incomplete code below, I have rows where company's board data from 2015 is being put in for years 2000-2015. I would just like the years without a Board entry for them (2000-2015)to just have NA entered in.

Here's the current code.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
library(glue)
setwd("~/Desktop/thesis")
library(readxl)
PAC <- read_excel("PAC.xlsx")
library(readxl)
Lobby <- read_excel("Lobby.xlsx")
library(readxl)
BoardData <- read_excel("BoardData.xlsx")
alldata <- left_join(PAC, Lobby, by="ultorg")
alldata <- left_join(alldata, BoardData, by=“ultorg”)
```

Thank you so much for any help you are able to give me! I really appreciate it and am able to answer any questions regarding my data.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: in your left_join calls, use `by = c("ultorg", "sector", "subind")` to avoid duplicating any of those columns. regarding the dates, i'd suggest creating a key column containing utlorg, sector, subind, and date in each dataset. That key column can be added as a joining variable in the 'by' input vector.

Comment: You do not need to keep calling `library` on same package. Call it once and it will persist in your environment.

Comment: Do you have a date column that is common in 3 tables? you must use one to obtain the effect you want.

Answer (score 1):

Merging by `ultorg`, `sector`, `subind` will work and if there is column that indicates about date, and it's common, then you should consider to add that column while joining them. Choice between `full_join` and `left_join` or etc are up to your purpose. Code below is one of example that you may try.

```
BoardData %>%
  full_join(PAC, by = c("ultorg", "sector", "subind")) %>% 
  full_join(Lobby, by = c("ultorg", "sector", "subind"))
```